# Route.get() returns Error while using imported file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have exported my functions in `index.js` and want to use them in `test.js`. But when I run `node test`, I get the below error message:

`Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`

What am I getting wrong and how can I fix it?

`index.js`

```
const axios = require("axios");
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:1888";

function getUsers(req, res) {
  const headers = {
    "APP-API-Version": "v2",
  };
  axios
    .get(`${BASE_URL}/users`, { headers })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response.data);
        res.send(response.data);
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
}
module.exports = getUsers;
```

`test.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const { getUsers } = require("./index.js");
const app = express();
const PORT = 3030;

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Running this application on the PORT ${PORT}`);
});


app.route("/users").get(getUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannnot use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) when requiring `getUsers` since the function itself is being exported. If the file with `getUsers` exported an object with `getUsers` as a property, then destructuring could be used (ie. `module.exports = { getUsers }`). This is why your error says `[object Undefined]`. Since that isn't the case, require `index.js` and name the variable `getUsers`.

#### TL;DR

Change
`const { getUsers } = require("./index.js");`
to
`const getUsers = require("./index.js");`

More info on CommonJS modules and how they work can be found within the [Node.js Module docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules-commonjs-modules).

Comment: When I change to this ```const getUsers = require("index.js");``` I get a different error: ```index is not defined```